# C#/WPF: Add Window.Style, even if a ResourceDictionary already exists

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to add two Datatriggers to my WPF Window. Normally, this would work via adding

```
`<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"></Style>`
```

to the Window.Resources.
In this case, I already have

```
`<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml" />`
```

in it. Is there a way to override the definitions from there?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <!-- Other stuff here -->
  <Style .../>
</ResourceDictionary>
```